# user 'postgres' doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

'postgres' user not created when i install postgreSQL 12 with EnterpriseDB, in installation process there is step in the beginning where you create superuser 'postgres' and give him password, but it's don't creates

```
% sudo -u postgres psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

It's not strange because i don't have user 'postgres' (that must be superuser), or any other users

[postgres no user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/449aU.png)

I tried fix it and create user by my self, but how i understand manually adding user don't change anything

Comment: "or any other users" You cannot have a running PostgreSQL database without at least one user.  You may have forgotten the name, but it must exist.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: macOS, i also don't understand how it's can be, and now after a day of trying to fix it i decided use brew install, it's working and i have superuser there and i can connect to database